# babeljs don't translate code

Tags: javascript, babeljs

i just install babeljs and try to translate my test code in file.js:

```
"use strict";

class Some {
  constructor(text = 'hello from es6') {
    console.log(text)
  }
}
```

but after run `babel file.js --out-file file.compile.js` i have the same contents in file.compile.js

next i try example from [babel cli usage page](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/):

```
babel-node -e "class Test { }"
```

and i get errors:

```
[eval]:1
class Test {}
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at _eval (c:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babelcli\lib\_babel-node.js:102:26)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel-node.js:122:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
at startup (node.js:136:18)
at node.js:972:3
```

my configuration:
os: windows 10
node: v5.0.0
npm: 3.3.6
babel: 6.1.1 (babel-core 6.0.20)

sorry for my english.

Comment: Babel 6 is a [major breaking change](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/), did you install *babel-preset-es2015*?

Comment: @Amit yes, i'm install it

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.